# UI issues with the "Registration" module

Tags: 7

I am working on my second Drupal 7 site and try integrating the "Registration" and "Registration Views" module (7.x-1.0-alpha5) the first time to create an event system where members can join events and see who else joined.

For this I've created a content type "Events" with the event-fields as well as a Registration Type for the events (with some additional registration fields on it). Then I added the registration as a field to "Events". So far so good - no problem here.

The issues I now have is with the User Interface:

a) The registration is rendered on top of the content as a tabbed-UI. I like to see just a link to register or maybe an embedded register-form. I also like to show the list of members who actually have registered for this event. ...maybe as a block on the sidebar or something like this. Can I change the way the registration module renders? Is there a way to create a block to render the registrants into?

b) In the event-nodes (only on the event-nodes - not on other node-types) I have the comments elements above the regular node content (in this case the event-field-contents) and below the registration-tabs. How do I control where the comments appear?

Any help or pointing whould be great!

Cheers, Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a lot of the issue is you you'll have to go into the theme and edit how it displays from there. The comments in particular you'll have to do this, you can create a tpl.php file specifically for for "Events" content type. You can learn how to do that here:

http://drupal.org/node/17565

Comment: It was in fact an issue with the Theme I used so I modified the given templates what fixed this issue.